# JSON.Parse Adding Unwanted Keys On a List of Objects

Tags: javascript, json

I am having trouble parsing a list of Objects for example:

If I write the code

```
JSON.parse("[{},{},{},{},{}]");
```

It returns

0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object

I was expecting it to return an array of 5 objects like this: 
[Object,Object,Object,Object,Object]

When I loop through the parsed object I get unwanted numbers. Is there a way of getting rid of the unwanted keys?

Comment: Is that a log statement you are showing? Because it looks like that is just showing empty objects a numerical keys 0-5, just like what you are trying to get.

Comment: It's JSON.parse (parse in lowercase) and it returns correctly an array of 5 objects in my browser.

Comment: "When I loop through" ...show the code.

Comment: Here is the code that I'm using to loop through the content. I'm new to JS, maybe I'm not doing this correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/ASMpB/

Answer (score 0):

calling `JSON.parse("[{},{},{},{},{}]")` will result in array, containing 5 empty json objects.

Don't be confused, the numbers represents the index of each object for readability. 
this function result the same as you expected: `[Object,Object,Object,Object,Object]`, but displayed with numbers to make the object more readable.

At the bottom line - **the numbers are NOT json keys**